# What does inverse_of: nil mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand what inverse_of does but I don't understand inverse_of: nil. 
So for example,

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: nil
end

class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

There is no association from author to book. Using author and book is probably a bad example, but I hope you get the idea. I see `inverse_of: nil` used a lot. So want to understand it.

Comment: could you also include `class Author`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It covers a `Mongoid` specific case where the opposite relationship isn't defined.

In your example, you would need to include `inverse_of: nil` in `class Book` **if** `class Author` doesn't use `has_many :books`.

Traditional case:

```
# app/models/book.rb
class Book
  field :title
  belongs_to :author
end

# app/models/author.rb
class Author
  field :name
  has_many :books
end
```

No opposing relationship case:

```
class Book
  field :title
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: nil
end

# here we use `get_books` instead of `has_many :books`
# so we need `inverse_of: nil` so Mongoid doesn't get confused
class Author
  field :name
  # has_many :books

  def get_books
    Book.in(author_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Further reading: http://dmitrypol.github.io/mongo/2016/12/05/habtm-inverse-nil.html#traditional-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Also, see [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) (which suggests using `false` instead of `nil`, but presumably both versions are equivalent.)